# OpenDayLight Toaster Tutorial Part 1

Tags: opendaylight

I'm confused on the structure for part 1 of the md-sal toaster tutorial.

`src/main/yang/toaster.yang
pom.xml`

or is it

`api/src/main/yang/toaster.yang
pom.xml`

When I `mvn clean install` with the 1st one, the project builds but does not generate any java code.  The second does not build but based on the tutorial, it should work.

Also, can I build this project from anywhere or does it need to be built in the `controller/opendaylight/md-sal/` path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the project from anywhere. In the checked-in Toaster project (part of Controller), the YANG module is in [`src/main/yang/toaster.yang`](https://github.com/opendaylight/controller/blob/master/opendaylight/md-sal/samples/toaster/src/main/yang/toaster.yang). If you build that project (the `toaster` module), you’ll find the generated Java code in `target/generated-sources/mdsal-binding/org/opendaylight/yang/gen/v1/http/netconfcentral/org/ns/toaster/rev091120/`.

Comment: Hey Thanks Stephen!

Answer (score 0):

As the link for this has changed (as it has for lot of OpenDaylight references) I'm adding an update to this post.

Pages that where "wiki" can now generally be found at "wiki-archive" (obviously haven't exhaustively tested that for all old ODL links).

The toaster tutorial (which are live as of 10/7/21) can now be found at the following link.

https://wiki-archive.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Toaster_Step-By-Step

Some of the code in the example fails to compile due to imports not being defined or specified. The code can be found in the "controller" project under "md-sal/samples". There's a link to this on the example page or you can download the project by running:

git clone https://github.com/opendaylight/controller.git